# Why are all irreps induced from irreps?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\pi$ be an irreducible representation of a (say finite) group $G$. I know it is a subrepresentation of the regular representation of $G$.

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the regular representation of $G$ is induced from the regular representation of $H$ (pretty trivially, parametrizing $G$ by $H\times G/H$).

I do not understand how to deduce from these facts that $\pi$ is induced from an irreducible representation of $H$.

Comment: You are right-- the thing you're trying to prove isn't true. For example, if $H$ is trivial, then its only irrep is the trivial rep. So it's not true that all irreps of $G$ are induced from irreps of $H$. (It's true that they're all subreps of such things.)

Comment: @hunter Oh, I guess I meant that they are induced for *some* subgroup $H$. Isn't this true either? (only subreps?)

Comment: I have posted my response to your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be extra careful with the quantifiers, I think what you're saying in the comments is that you want to know:

¿ For all finite $G$, for all irreducible representations of $G$,
there exists $H \lneq G$ such that $\rho$ is induced from an irreducible representation of $H$ ?

The answer is still no. For example, if $G$ is cyclic of prime order $p$ then $G$ has $p$ irreducible representations. On the other hand, its only subgroup besides itself is $\{1\}$, whose induced representation is the regular representation.

(If we allow $H=G$ then the answer is yes, since $\rho$ is then induced from itself.)